# How to use gitbook plugin in gitbook style bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown, gitbook

There is a simple procedure to put buttons for copying code of gitbooks. What would be the way to do that in a bookdown?

```
# install npm
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# install gitbook builder
sudo npm install -g gitbook
sudo npm install -g gitbook-cli

# git clone gitbook "example" repository
git clone ...

cd gitbook/
npm init

# Install plugin to add clipboard button for code 
# https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-copy-code-button
npm install gitbook-plugin-copy-code-button
```

Create index.md

- in this case, in Rstudio, New file>R Markdown>From Template>github

and make `book.json`:

```
{
"structure": {
    "readme": "index.md"
},
  "plugins": ["copy-code-button"]
}
```

Finally, `gitbook build .`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[We just added the `Copy` button](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/pull/776) in the development version of **bookdown**. You may test it via

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

To answer your original question: currently there is no way to use gitbook plugins in **bookdown**.