# Is there a way to do a glossary in R Bookdown?

Tags: bookdown, gitbook

I am attempting to add a glossary to a [bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown)-generated document in gitbook style.

Glossary: a bunch of terms which should contain definition, be linked to from the main text, and optionally link back to locations in the text (or a pre-configured Search to find all occurrences)

An example is https://www.npmjs.com/package/gitbook-plugin-glossary-tooltip.

A while back, Yihui [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031410/3207444) that there was (at the time) no way to use gitbook plugins on bookdown.

Question: is that still true, and/or is there an alternate way of adding a glossary to a bookdown generated website?

Comment: It's not officially supported at this time. You may subscribe to this Github issue in case it is resolved in the future: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/199

Comment: What about the gitbook plugins part? I'm happy if it only works on one platform for now.

Comment: Gitbook plugins are not supported, either. Sorry.